# Creating keycloak users through spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to create a keycloak object to register new user with keycloak with the following code:

```
public Keycloak getInstance() {
    if (keycloak == null) {

        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .realm(realm)
                .serverUrl(serverURL)
                .clientId(clientID)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
    }
    return keycloak;
}
```

But i keep getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ResteasyClientBuilderImpl cannot be cast to class javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder (org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ResteasyClientBuilderImpl and javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
> at org.keycloak.admin.client.ClientBuilderWrapper.create(ClientBuilderWrapper.java:29) ~[keycloak-admin-client-17.0.1.jar:17.0.1]
> at org.keycloak.admin.client.spi.ResteasyClientClassicProvider.newRestEasyClient(ResteasyClientClassicProvider.java:35) ~[keycloak-admin-client-17.0.1.jar:17.0.1]
> at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.newRestEasyClient(Keycloak.java:98) ~[keycloak-admin-client-17.0.1.jar:17.0.1]
> at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:89) ~[keycloak-admin-client-17.0.1.jar:17.0.1]
> at org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder.build(KeycloakBuilder.java:146) ~[keycloak-admin-client-17.0.1.jar:17.0.1]
> at com.microfinanceBank.Customer.Config.KeycloakProvider.getInstance(KeycloakProvider.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.microfinanceBank.Customer.service.KeycloakAdminClientServices.wow(KeycloakAdminClientServices.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.microfinanceBank.Customer.controller.CustomerController.getCustomer(CustomerController.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.microfinanceBank.Customer.controller.CustomerController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8c9f9beb.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]

Below are my keycloak dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
   <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
   <version>17.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.guicedee.services</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What am i doing wrong?

I have tried adding some dependencies yet keep getting error.
Please what should i do.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please someone should help out

Comment: Hi @ferrocene, I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution to it?

Comment: Yes it took me weeks.. The issue was with the dependency. I had to remove all rest easy dependencies since later versions were unsupported then added only latest keycloak admin client dependency. As of now it's version 18.0.0.. Let me know if it works

Comment: Also make sure your server url is the port which keycloak is running something like "http:// localhost:8080/" do not use "http:// localhost:8080/auth" as seen in examples

Answer (score 2):

`keycloak-spring-boot-starter` [is deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187), don't use it. You might find alternatives [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)

I wouldn't use `keycloak-admin-client` neither. Admin API is quite well [documented](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/#_users_resource). Just use your favorite REST client (with spring-boot features to configure OAuth2 REST client if you like) and POST a request to your Keycloak server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keycloak's SDK for your springboot application. Include these two dependencies in the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>18.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
  <version>18.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

After that create a keycloak's instance in your springboot application.

```
public Keycloak getAdminKeycloakUser() {
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl("keycloak-auth-url")
            .grantType("password").realm("realm-name")
            .clientId("client-id")
            .username("admin-user")
            .password("admin-password")
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()).build();
}
```

The above method will get you the admin user which is needed in order to create users into Keycloak.
The next step would be to get the realm as realm manages users.

```
public RealmResource getRealm() {
    return getAdminKeycloakUser().realm(realm);
}
```

Finally now you can create user by using `org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation`.

```
public void createUser() {
    UserRepresentation userRepresentation = new UserRepresentation();

    userRepresentation.setUsername("username");
    userRepresentation.setFirstName("first-name");
    userRepresentation.setLastName("last-name");
    userRepresentation.setEmail("test@email.com");

    Response response = getRealm().realmResource.users().create(userRepresentation);
    //If user is created successfully 200 is returned for response status.

    //Set password flow
    CredentialRepresentation passwordCred = new CredentialRepresentation();
    String userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);
    passwordCred.setTemporary(false);
    passwordCred.setType("password");
    passwordCred.setValue("some-password");
    UserResource userResource = realmResource.users().get(userId);
    userResource.resetPassword(passwordCred);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserRepresentation userRepresentation = new UserRepresentation();
userRepresentation.setUsername("username");
userRepresentation.setFirstName("first-name");
userRepresentation.setLastName("last-name");
userRepresentation.setEmail("test@email.com");
// set other required values

javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = KeycloakBuilder.builder().build().realm("your-realm-nam").users().create(userRepresentation);
if (response != null && response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Family.SUCCESSFUL) 
{
    return org.keycloak.admin.client.CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);        // returns String (Id of created User)
}
```